# Creating a BitSet of specific length in java

Tags: java, c#, bitset

I have a function inside which I would like to performs operations such OR, AND, set and others. I first thought about an array of boolean, but the problem with that is that I can not perform the AND and OR operations on them (I could however set a particular elements to true). I also tried to used BiSet, but the problem is that the minimum size of BitSet is 64 (bits). I would like it to store a specific number of bits (15 for example) from which I can iterate through later on to get their contains. In C#, there is the BitArray Class that deals with such problem; Java does not seem to have such. Any suggestions for this problem will highly be appreciated

Comment: Why doesn't ```new BitSet(15)``` fulfill your needs?

Comment: So, the really interesting question is more like: what gave you that wrong impression?

Comment: @cdelmas , I said that because, when I do for example: BitSet a = new BiSet(15), after when I call a.length, I get 64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are mistaken. [java.util.Bitset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#BitSet(int)) allows for any number of bits; there is no "only > 64 bits" limitation. Yes, the bitset is probably internally using long values to store those bits; but nowhere does it say that you can only use 64 bit, 128, and so.

In other words: when you setup a Bitset for 15 bits, it will allocate `long[1]`; same for 63 bits; and if you need 70 bits, it will allocate `long[2]`.

Long story short: this class is exactly what you are looking for; and I don't see that any other implementation could be vastly more efficient or so.

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation, It is now clear to me. Can I also create  an array of BiSet, and if yes, how do I iterate through them?

Comment: Well, probably you would start by reading some books on Java. You see, this is not "programming school" where people tell you stuff that is really documented all over the place. But, well; you would be going for `Bitset[] mySets = new BitSet[] { new BitSet(5), new BitSet(6), .. } ` . But in 2016, you most likely want to use dynamic collections, like `List<BitSet> mySets = new ArrayList<>()` ... and then add BitSet objects as needed. But as said: this is really basic stuff that you learn by *studying*; not by asking people on stackoverflow.